# Having trouble with executeMyFriendsRequestAsync

Tags: android, facebook

For some reason even though I have copied this code almost exactly from the sample, I cannot seem to actually see any of my friends' info. I'm using a fake account with only a few friends. Can someone give me an idea of what could be going wrong?

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
     @Override
     public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
         if (session.isOpened()) {
         Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
        @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
         Log.d("INFO", "on complete");
         Log.i("INFO", "" + users.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Runnable getFacebookUserInfo = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(facebookConnector.getFacebook()
                .getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
            {
                //...   
            }
        });

        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(facebookConnector.getFacebook()
                .getSession(), new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                if (users != null) {
                    List<String> friendsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (GraphUser user : users) {
                        friendsList.add(user.getId());
                        //...
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

};

I think it useful.